# Does the time-lagged correlation between $\ce{CO2}$ and ocean temperature have a shorter timelag than the one between $\ce{CO2}$ and air temperature?

Tags: atmosphere, climate, paleoclimatology

I'm talking about evidence from both proxy records in the last 50,000 years (if possible) and the recent past (if also possible)

Comment: The mechanisms that give rise to correlations between temperature and CO2 on long timescales (e.g. paleoclimate - temperature driven ocean degassing?) and shorter timescales (e.g. the instrumental record - variations in vegetation in the Americas resulting from ENSO?) are unlikely to be the same.  Also I don't know whether there are any suitable ocean temperature proxy records.  It would be helpful if you could give some more information about what inspired the question.